# Minimization over the integers

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am nearly sure this question has been asked earlier but I do not find an answer.

Is there a way to solve this minimization in Mathematica

```
Minimize[{Abs[1.2 - x] + Abs[3.3 - y] + Abs[1.6 - z] && 
  x + y + z == 5 && x ∈ Integers && y ∈ Integers &&
  z ∈ Integers}, {x, y, z}]
```

When I run the command or change to `NMinimize` or `FindMininimum`, I receive the infamous message

```
NMinimize::nnum: The function value False is not a number at {x,y,z} = {0.673558,0.659492,0.0861047}.
```

But since for this specific value, the absolute value in the  3 cases is positive, I do not understand why Mathematica send this message. Of course this optimization can be transformed  in a linear program.

For information, this problem is a simplification of an apportionment problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the usage of `Minimize`!

```
Minimize[{Abs[1.2 - x] + Abs[33/10 - y] + Abs[16/10 - z], 
  x + y + z == 5 && x ∈ Integers && y ∈ Integers && 
   z ∈ Integers}, {x, y, z}]
(* {1.1, {x -> 1, y -> 3, z -> 1}} *)
```

Comment: So evident Thanks ! But why have you replace real numbers by  rational at least two times

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki I didn't see your mistake at first and thought it might be that Mathematica can't handle reals when solving for integers. Didn't take out when I copied it.